# TextBox issue populating after postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using ASP.NET and C# couple text boxes to calculate results entered. Textbox2 has a value entered and on button click Textbox1 gets populated. This works fine the first time I enter the value. But the second time I change the value in Textbox2, I see that the value is being assigned to Textbox1 while debugging on Button click, but doesn't show up on the screen. I have many other controls and a master page. The textboxes are within an update panel.

Backend code on button click is:

```
decimal @val1 = 0;
decimal @val2 = 0;
decimal @val3 = 0;
@val2 = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(txtID3.Text), 2);
@val1 = Convert.ToDecimal(Textbox2.Text);
@val3 = @val1 / (1 - @val2 / 100);
TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(@val3);
```

Can someone help me what's going on?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" Width="150px" TabIndex="6" MaxLength="8"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
  ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Textbox1" 
  ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Textbox2" Width="150px" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgCalc" ImageUrl="~/Resource/Images/calrate_0.bmp"
  onmouseout="this.src='../Resource/Images/calrate_0.bmp'"
  onmouseover="this.src='../Resource/Images/calrate_1.bmp'"
  Height="25px" Width="25px" Visible="false" onclick="imgCalc_Click" />
```

Comment: Sounds like an update panel issue. Both the boxes and button are on the same update panel? What's the update mode on it? Need more code details.....

Comment: Hello Admin, I am sorry about that. I did not know how to add code before to the query. But I will keep that in mind to not post twice.

Comment: Vivek: thank you for replying. Below is what in updatepanel     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">...and yes both the textboxes are inside the udpatepanel.

Comment: Fixed it... All I had to do was to add <Trigger> <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="buttonid" /></Trigger>  Thanks guys..